# token from cookie not being sent. Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, cookies, session-cookies

```
const uri = MONGODB_URI;
const client = new MongoClient(MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: uri,
    collection: 'sessions',
    autoReconnect: true,
    autoRemove: 'native' // Default
  });
store.on('error', function(error) {
    console.error('Session store error:', error);
  });
app.use(session({
    secret: JWT_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    proxy: true,
    store: store,
    cookie: { secure: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }
  }));
```

I have this /signup route so when a new user comes in from a referral URL, the user gets signed up and then gets redirected to that original URL after getting signed up.

```
app.post('/signup', upload.single('myfile'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
      winston.info('Received signup request');
  
      const formFields = JSON.parse(req.body.formFields);
      const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = formFields;
      const referredBy = req.query.referralId; // The ID of the person who referred the user (if any)
      const referralId = uuidv4(); // The unique ID for this user to refer others
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
      const user = { firstName, lastName, email, password: hashedPassword, referredBy, referralId };
      const userCollection = client.db('instadb').collection('users');
      const existingUser = await userCollection.findOne({ email: email });
      
  
      if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(409).json({ error: 'Email already exists' });
      }
      const result = await userCollection.insertOne(user);
  
      if (result.acknowledged) {
        winston.info('User created successfully:', result.insertedId);
  
        // Create a JWT token for the user
        const jwtToken = jwt.sign({ userId: result.insertedId }, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' });  
        if (req.file) {
          const file = req.file;
          const fileContent = file.buffer;
          const fileExtension = path.extname(file.originalname);
  
          const filename = `${uuidv4()}${fileExtension}`;
          const params = {
            Bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: filename,
            Body: fileContent
          };
  
          await uploadFileToS3(params, result.insertedId.toString());
          winston.info('File uploaded and reference saved');
        }
  
        // Retrieve the original URL from the session
        const originalUrl = req.session.originalUrl;
        console.log('ORIGINAL URL FROM SESSION', req.session.originalUrl)

        // Redirect to the original URL if present, otherwise redirect to the user's profile
        const redirectUrl = originalUrl ? originalUrl : `/rate_profile?userId=${result.insertedId.toString()}`;
        console.log('FINAL REDIRECT URL', redirectUrl)
        // Clear the originalUrl from the session
        req.session.originalUrl = null;
        
        return res.json({ redirectUrl: redirectUrl });
     
      } else {
        winston.error('Failed to create user in MongoDB');
        res.status(500).send('Failed to create user');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      winston.error('Error creating user:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create user' });
    }
  });
```

when there is a token in the cookie, the originalURL becomes undefined or null for some reason, when there is no token from the cookie(token is undefined) the originalURL is correct,but the user is sent to their own page instead of the originalURL. it is very random. Although, the same logic works correctly in /login, without fail.

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    winston.info('Received login request');

    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const userCollection = client.db('instadb').collection('users');
    const user = await userCollection.findOne({ email });

    if (!user) {
      winston.info('User not found');
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }

    const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!passwordMatch) {
      winston.info('Invalid password');
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid password' });
    }

    // Create a JWT token for the user
    const jwtToken = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' });

    // Set the JWT token in a cookie
    res.cookie('token', jwtToken, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 3600000, secure: true });

    winston.info('Login successful');
    
    // Return the user ID as a JSON response instead of redirecting
    return res.json({ userId: user._id.toString() });
    
  } catch (error) {
    winston.error('Error during login:', error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Login failed' });
  }
});
```

This seems like an issue with Google App Engine due to proxy being used maybe. I have tried numerous ways to set the cookie but cannot get it to work.https is enforced. `trust_proxy` is enforced. Not sure what the problem is or where to look.There is no session being saved to MongoDB.